# Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django, web-services

EDIT: Original issue is fixed. I need to add the protocol http:// infront of the url for the parameter of xmlttp.open(). New issue: Django is refusing the request: "POST 127.0.0.1:8000/data 403 (FORBIDDEN)"

I have a form that is submitted through my AJAX function runAJAX(). This  function does a POST request to the server. The problem is that the server is not getting the request. If instead of a url parameter, if leave the url parameter blank "" for xmlhttp.open() only then does the console log on the server backend show a POST request being made but the server denies it in this case. My question is how do i go about passing that POST request successfully? What am i doing wrong? The server is hosted locally on my machine(127.0.0.1:8000). Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000 will fetch index.html.

Error message in browser log upon hitting the submit button for my form:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load %3127.0.0.1:8000/data/. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
runAJAX @       (index):44
stopDefAction   @       (index):51



Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '%3127.0.0.1:8000/data/'.

runAJAX @       (index):44
stopDefAction   @       (index):51
```

My code(Javascript, HTML index.html, Django backend urls.py and views.py files):

```js
function runAJAX(){
xmlhttp.open("POST","127.0.0.1:8000/data/",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var searchtype = document.getElementById("searchtype").innerHTML;
var subreddit = document.getElementById("subreddit").innerHTML;
xmlhttp.send("searchtype=" + searchtype + "&subreddit=" + subreddit);
}

function stopDefAction(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    runAJAX();
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener(
    'click', stopDefAction, false
);

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

```html
<div id="center">
    <h1 id="h01">Reddit Link</h1>

    <p id="p01">A Subreddit Recommender System</p>

    <form id="subreddit">
        <select id=searchtype name="searchtype" form="subreddit">
            <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
            <option value="Accurate">Accurate</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="subreddit" placeholder="AskReddit"/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    <p id="pdone">0%</p>
</div>
```

Django root urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'', include('redditlink.urls')),]
```

Webapp urls.py file:

`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^data/$', views.data, name='data'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),]`

views.py file:

```
def index(request):
      template = loader.get_template('redditlink/index.html')
      return HttpResponse(template.render())


def data(request):
    print("1")
    subreddit_name = request.GET["subreddit"].lower()
    search_type = request.GET["searchtype"]
```

Comment: maybe you need to specify the protocol scheme ? ex: `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/"`

Comment: yep that did the job, thanks! Now i just need to figure out why django is refusing the request: "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)"

Comment: I don't know ... but you should edit your post to reflect your progression

Comment: add @csrf_exempt decorator on top of every function in views.